# pthread library basic example does not work properly

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

I am looking for pthread on C. So I am new. I am trying to learn syntax and roles of pointers in pthread code. Can anyone tell me, whats my mistakes according to code? I cant understand clearly, what I did.

When I'm trying to check the return value `pthread_create()` I'm getting wrong / random values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int *f_1,*f_2,*f_3,*f_4;

void p1(void *a);
void p2(void *a);
void p3(void *a);
void p4(void *a);

int main(void){
pthread_t thread_1, thread_2, thread_3, thread_4;
int *x=1,*y=2,*z=3,*w=4;

f_1=pthread_create(&thread_1, NULL, p1,(void *)x);
f_2=pthread_create(&thread_2, NULL, p2,(void *) y);
f_3=pthread_create(&thread_3, NULL, p1,(void *) z);
f_4=pthread_create(&thread_4, NULL, p1,(void *) w);

pthread_join(thread_1,NULL);
pthread_join(thread_2,NULL);
pthread_join(thread_3,NULL);
pthread_join(thread_4,NULL);


printf("Hi! From %d. thread!",f_1);
printf("Hi! From %d. thread!",f_2);
printf("Hi! From %d. thread!",f_3);
printf("Hi! From %d. thread!",f_4);

return 0;
}
void p1(void *a){
f_1=(int *)a;
}

void p2(void *a){
f_2=(int *)a;
}

void p3(void *a){
f_3=(int *)a;
}

void p4(void *a){
f_4=(int *)a;
}
```

Comment: `I cant understand clearly, what i did.`... Question: then how did _you_ do it?

Comment: Can you at least explain what you were *trying* to do, and what *specific* problems you are having with this code?

Comment: From some websites, but it was not compiled.

Comment: why this code not running? Question is this.

Comment: I have edited the question (as per the response received on my answer), please revert if I broke something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pthread_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) returns an  `int`, you're trying to store that in a `int *` (pointer). That is implementation defined behavior.

```
f_1=pthread_create(&thread_1, NULL, p1,(void *)x);
f_2=pthread_create(&thread_2, NULL, p2,(void *) y);
f_3=pthread_create(&thread_3, NULL, p1,(void *) z);
f_4=pthread_create(&thread_4, NULL, p1,(void *) w);
```

Next, you're using `%d` to print pointers,

```
printf("Hi! From %d. thread!",f_1);
printf("Hi! From %d. thread!",f_2);
printf("Hi! From %d. thread!",f_3);
printf("Hi! From %d. thread!",f_4);
```

which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To solve both the above issues, all your `f_n` variables should be `int` type, not `int *`s.

That said, the function prototype for thread functions is

```
void *(*start_routine) (void *)
```

which is a function returning `void *` and accepting a `void *`. You may want to change the function signature and definition of your thread functions according to that.

Comment: you say that, i cant return value from sub-fuctions, with a pthread_create() ?

Comment: @outSider I'm talking about the return value of `pthread_create()` function call itself, please see the linked man page.

Comment: ok, i will try now.

Answer (score 0):

I think your thread functions should be pointer to void, for example:

```
void *p1(void *arg);
void *p2(void *arg);
```

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_create.txt

Look for "Example: Pthread Creation and Termination" here
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/